# How to avoid null-pointers in multi-threading on the same List?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Say, I have a vector of dynamic object pointers and have different threads working on those objects.

It is possible that while one thread is working on an object, the main thread is deleting it. It does this by setting a flag in the object to mark it for deletion and then starting to free up its memory.

I have thought about taking care of this by checking for the flag before each single access to the object, but theoretically the following could happen (example code for illustration, although I am trying to make it reflect the situation as best as possible there could still be errors in it):

```
object = copyPointerFromVector(someIndex);

if(!object->markedForDeletion){
---flag set, object cleaned up by main thread and erased from vector 
  object->getValues(something); //crash with access violation
}
```

While it is probably rare this of course is still unacceptable. As someone obviously very very rusty with multi-threading, what is the right way of solving this issue?

Comment: You can either grab a mutex for the object before doing the check or use [`double-checking`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) idiom.

Comment: Just one note: You write "the main thread", but there is no such things in most threading environments. In particular, there is no parent-child or master-slave relation between threads. Even the thread that runs `main()` is just one thread. Perhaps the only difference is what happens when the thread that's running `main()` terminates.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The main thread was only mentioned to put an emphasis on it being an entirely different thing and not a case of managing synchronization of thread copies. I would personally consider the thread that is responsible for managing the other threads, the "main thread" or "management thread" of that thread-pool. Please correct me if that is an erroneous way of choosing your terms.

Comment: Please show more of your code. Most probably you have a race condition. Do you use smart pointers? If not you should use them.

Answer (score 2):

Note up front: I assume you know about synchronization (mutexes, condition variables, atomics etc), i.e. the primitive building blocks used for multithreaded programming and that your question is about how to use them. You need those basics.

The problem you have is basically one of unclear ownership, not one of synchronization. Of course, ownership between threads requires synchronization, so it is also involved. Still, when one part of your program is destroying a shared object while another part is still using it, it's because it wrongly assumes it was the sole owner and could dispose of the object. More generally, in multithreading, you could also say that it changes data structures without synchronization, but this case is special enough and there are according tools to deal with it.

The tools to deal with this are called reference counting and garbage collection. Of those, the easiest to apply is probably reference counting. For that, all you need is a smart pointer that keeps track of the number of owners of an object. For example, `std::shared_ptr` gives you exactly that and it manages the reference count in a thread-safe way. In order to "delete" an object from the mentioned vector, you just remove the smart pointer. If the refcount goes to zero, it was the last one and gets deleted for you.

Garbage collection is a bit more complex. It involves scanning your process memory for references/pointers to objects and deleting the objects which aren't referenced any more. This requires installing a garbage collector though and it's a more complex change to an existing program.

Comment: I like to add the note that only the reference counter of `shared_ptr` is "atomic". The access to the object still has to be managed. This is often forgotten, which leads to UB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I must admit I have a little trouble understanding it. I fail to see how garbage collection is relevant for synchonization for example. Additonally, disposing of an object while another thread is still working on it should actually be intended behavior, with the other thread detecting it and stopping work on that object/terminating (whichever is currently necessary, depending on how the thread itself is programmed) on such occasion (or being terminated/told to skip it, whichever is the agreed upon/tried and trusted way).

Comment: Concerning the claim that disposing of an object should be detected, I disagree. Yes, if you watch it from a high enough level, it could look like that. However, under the hood, you don't dispose of an object in use, which causes a so-called dangling reference. Instead, you communicate with the other involved parties, so they stop work and release the object and you can finally dispose it safely.